# JPA : multiple transactions

Tags: java, jpa, transactions, eclipselink

I'm trying to make 2 different DB calls with the same transaction entity. I know that I can make both interrogations between `begin()` and `commit()` but I'm trying this for educational purposes only.

```
EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();
EventService eventService = new EventService();
transaction.begin();
Event currentEvent = eventService.read(eventId);
transaction.commit();

if (currentEvent != null){
    CommentService commentService = new CommentService();
    transaction.begin();
    commentList = commentService.getList(1, id, 50);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

This piece of code throws :

> Exception Description: Transaction is currently active

which is normal knowing that I'm attempting a `begin()` to an already opened transaction.

Is it correct to exclude the second `transaction.begin()`  and just use `commit()` whenever I have to work with the DB?

**LE:**
I'm using EclipseLink and RESOURCE_LOCAL

Comment: What happens if you reobtain the transaction from the EntityManager between the first commit() and the second begin()?

Comment: Same thing happens. after the first .begin() the .isActive() will always return true until I'm closing the EntityManager.

Comment: Can you print off the em.getClass() and transaction.getClass() to see what implementation is being used?  EclipseLink's transaction implementation will mark the transaction as inactive in a finally block on commit(), so it could be a wrapper is not passing the call through directly.  Which version of EclipseLink are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the `transacton-type` is set to `RESOURCE_LOCAL`.
In this cases you must create some `SingleTon` classes which should handle the `EntityManager` and the `EntityTransaction`.

Answer (score 0):

Odd.  This should work.  What JPA provider are you using?  Perhaps enable logging to see what is going on.

Comment: EclipseLink and the transaction-type is RESOURCE_LOCAL